# Check an array if there are two or more of same elements in a row

Tags: python, numpy

I have an input array

```
    1 2 2
    3 2 1
    1 2 2
    1 2 3
    1 1 3
```

My output should be

```
    3 2 1
    1 2 3
```

This means all the elements repeated in the rows should be deleted. Is it possible to do that in numpy?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), and show your code. Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [**minimal reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first sort each row and then look at the differences between consecutive elements per row: if there is *any* 0 in a row, it means that row has duplicates and needs to be dropped:

```
# sort and take the difference within rows
sorted_arr = np.sort(arr)
diffs = np.diff(sorted_arr)

# form a boolean array: does a row contain any duplicates?
to_drop = (diffs == 0).any(axis=1)

# invert the mask and index into original array
result = arr[~to_drop]
```

to get

```
>>> result

array([[3, 2, 1],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

Comment: That is great. Thank you Mustafa Aydin.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Hichkas's answer but implemented with numpy

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1,2,2],
              [3,2,1],
              [1,2,2],
              [1,2,3],
              [1,1,3]])

ans = np.empty((0,3), int)

for row in x:
    if row.shape[0] <= np.unique(row).shape[0]:
        ans = np.vstack((ans,row))

print(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
list_test = [  [1 ,2 ,2],
    [3 ,2 ,1],
    [1 ,2 ,2],
    [1 ,2 ,3],
    [1 ,1 ,3]]
for x in list_test:
    if len(x)>len(set(x)):
        list_test.remove(x)
```

Comment: Thanks Hichkas! I would like to know whether any numpy version is available as the matrix is very large.

Comment: `del x` doesn't delete the element from the list. The original `list_test` will still be the same. You need to create a new list which excludes the values you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [[1,2,2],
     [3,2,1],
     [1,2,2],
     [1,2,3],
     [1,1,3]]
[*filter(lambda x: set(x).__len__() > 2, x)]
# [[3, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3]]

# or rewritten for numpy
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1,2,2],
     [3,2,1],
     [1,2,2],
     [1,2,3],
     [1,1,3]])
np.array([*filter(lambda x: set(x.tolist()).__len__() > 2, x)])
# array([[3, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3]])
```